# Getting exception StartEdit on DevExpress Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, devexpress

I have a patial view with following code(with custom data binding):

Partial View

```
@{

Html.EnableClientValidation();

Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();

    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings => {
        settings.Name = "GridView1";
        settings.KeyFieldName = "StudentId";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "CustomBinding", Action = "MyGridViewPartial" };

        settings.CustomActionRouteValues = new { Controller = "Editing", Action = "ChangeEditModePartial" };

        settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "CustomBinding", Action = "GridView1PartialAddNew" };

        settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "CustomBinding", Action = "GridView1PartialUpdate" };

        settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "CustomBinding", Action = "GridView1PartialDelete" };
        settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditFormAndDisplayRow;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;
        settings.SettingsPopup.EditForm.Width = 600;

        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowNewButton = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowDeleteButton = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowEditButton = true;


        settings.CustomBindingRouteValuesCollection.Add(
       GridViewOperationType.Paging,
       new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "MyPagingAction" }
   );

        settings.CustomBindingRouteValuesCollection.Add(
        GridViewOperationType.Sorting,
        new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "MySortingAction" }
    );
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptivityMode = GridViewAdaptivityMode.Off;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptiveColumnPosition = GridViewAdaptiveColumnPosition.Left;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptiveDetailColumnCount = 1;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AllowOnlyOneAdaptiveDetailExpanded = false;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.HideDataCellsAtWindowInnerWidth = 0;


        settings.Columns.Add("StudentId");
        settings.Columns.Add("StudentName");
        settings.Columns.Add("StudentAge");
        settings.Columns.Add("StudentGrade");
        settings.Columns.Add("StudentAddress");

        settings.PreRender = (sender, e) =>
        {

            ((MVCxGridView)sender).StartEdit(0);/**//This is the Exception line**
        };
        settings.CellEditorInitialize = (s, e) =>
        {
            ASPxEdit editor = (ASPxEdit)e.Editor;
            editor.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;

        };
            });
        if (ViewData["EditError"] != null){
        grid.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
    }
}
@grid.BindToCustomData(Model).GetHtml()///Custom binding
```

Please suggest the solutions:

**Exception:**
A primary key field specified via the KeyFieldName property is not found in the underlying data source. Make sure the field name is spelled correctly. Pay attention to the character case.

Comment: Are you sure that the Model contains (StudentId) property and you retrieve it from db successfully ?

Comment: from DevExpressForum :
the required field is not marked with the "public" keyword or does not have "get"/"set" accessors. It is necessary to implement the "get"/"set" accessors for used fields/properties;

Comment: Thanks Ahmed Ragheb, got the solution "Student ID" was not in proper format means it was wrongly inscribed "StudentID" instead of "StudentId"  thanks for your guidance

Comment: Can I add it as a answer as other can see and help them

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the Model contains (StudentId) property and you retrieve it from db successfully and also it is public with getter and setter